# How to check for the correct answer

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

After importing db to assets, i succesfully read from it, and assign random answers to four of my buttons in my activity:

```
try{    
        mDbHelper.open();  //open db

        Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData();

        question.setText(c.getString(1));

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        labels.add(c.getString(2));
        labels.add(c.getString(3));
        labels.add(c.getString(4));
        labels.add(c.getString(5));

        Collections.shuffle(labels);

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3));
        }
        finally{    // close db
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
```

My correct answer is always c.getString(2) (I have a column in my sqlite db set as ANSWER and it has an ID=2). After that I set onClickListener for each button to realod activity with another question:

```
bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());

            }
        });
```

How to check what is correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Cast your `View` to a `Button`

```
Button btn = (Button) v;
```

Then compare the label

```
if (btn.getText().equals(c.getString(2)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Cursor might have been closed when user clicks on this button, that's why tagging approach would be better.

Comment: This is true, definitely. I just assumed that because he's starting a new `Activity` after the question is answered, that perhaps his `Cursor` is loaded and closed in `onStart` and `onDestroy`. Assumptions, pfft ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Updated my answer, please check:

```
 private class Answer {
        public Answer(String opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        String option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }

List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

    labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
    labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

    Collections.shuffle(labels);

    bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
    bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
    bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
    bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
    bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
    bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
    bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
    bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
    bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

OnClickListener for all buttons:

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
        if (ans.isCorrect) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This won't work, as he doesn't know which `Button` is being assigned the correct answer, due to the shuffle.

Comment: I get error "clickListener cannot be resolved to a variable"...the ones in perentaces. I'm calling all of this under my onCreate method. Is that right?

Comment: Put it separately as if it was a method.

Comment: Yeah, i just wanted to post that I put it outside of methods and it worked like a charm. :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like it's working but when I try to check if it's working something weird is heppening. I've inserted startActivity(new Intent("rs.mypackage.TACANODGOVOR")); right after if (ans.isCorrect) { but I don't get that popup activity(it's a themed activity). It just goes on next question. But when i press back on my phone i get that popup. :))) I get all the popups, right and wrong ones as I go backwards. What am I doing wrong? I also added the else statement for wrong answer. I don't know why i can't post my code here in reply.

Comment: It might be something else. Post another question and accept it as an answer as it solved what you were looking for. In other question please post some code about how you are doing it and I will definitely look into that question.

Comment: OK, cause with Toast it is fine. I'm making another thread right now. thanks.

Comment: Here's the link:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142333/how-to-load-themed-activity-after-correct-or-wrong-answer-in-a-quiz)

Answer (score 0):

Button b = (Button)v; 
    if (b.getText().toString().equals(c.getString(2))){

```
    // answer is correct
}
```

Not very elegant but that should do it.

Comment: This is incorrect. `View` doesn't have a method called `getText()`