# How to load themed activity after correct or wrong answer in a quiz?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

OK, I was adviced to make a new thread for my question. I am using imported SQLite database. Anyway, I have made two themed dialogs for right and wrong answers, and I want to show them when right or wrong answer is clicked. Here's the code in my activity, cut out parts:

```
private class Answer {
        public Answer(String opt, boolean correct) {
            option = opt;
            isCorrect = correct;
        }

        String option;
        boolean isCorrect;
    }

    final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                Toast toastT = Toast.makeText(Kviz.this, "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toastT.show();
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast toastP = Toast.makeText(Kviz.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toastP.show();
                }
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
    };
```

When I use Toast like above it works fine, but when I try to use my themed activity like this, it doesn't, instead it goes right to next question, and when I press back button on my phone I get that themed popup activity:

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Answer ans = (Answer) v.getTag();
            if (ans.isCorrect) {
                Intent t = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.TACANODGOVOR");
                startActivity(t);
                finish();
            }else{
                    Intent p = new Intent("rs.androidaplikacijekvizopstekulture.POGRESANODGOVOR");
                    startActivity(p);
                }
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
    };
```

To repeat, I get the themed activity when I press the back button, I get the wrong ones and the correct ones, as I go backwards. I just want to show that dialog and then to load the next question, like it does with the Toast. Just to mention that this activity loading works fine in my other acitivity, only it goes after simple button click, no question and answers.

Comment: Tell me the flow you want when answer is correct and when answer is wrong.

Comment: Right now I just want the display message (that themed dialog) to be shown for right and wrong answer, and after 10 questions, i want to exit the Kviz activity. I tried to place the counter++; right bellow startActivity(t); but i didn't find where to put while or if loop. On the same place I can place counterWrong (in the else scope) to count 5 wrong answers and exit the activity, but also didn't find where to place the while or if loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is after calling any of (right/wrong) `startActivity`, it moves on to call `startActivity(getIntent());` method. One way is to make your TACANODGOVOR & POGRESANODGOVOR Dialog activity by adding following tag/value for these activities in manifest file `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` e.g.

```
<activity ... android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

It will display TACANODGOVOR & POGRESANODGOVOR as dialog and unless user presses back button (or any exit button activities may have), it wont proceed to next line.

Comment: my TACANODGOVOR & POGRESANODGOVOR activities are already theme dialog. I have android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog line in manifest.